# Live search in Rails 4 with JS and Keyup

Tags: javascript, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails app that needs live search (show results via JS/Ajax as user is typing).  This is the code I've written so far.

**application.js**

```
$(function() {
  $("#email_search input").keyup(function() {
  $.get($("#email_search").attr("action"), $("#email_search").serialize(), null, "script");
return false;
   });
 });
```

**_email.html.erb partial**

```
<%= form_tag emails_path, :method => 'get', remote: true, :id => "email_search" do %>

  <%= text_field_tag :search,  params[:search], :placeholder => 'Search From, Subject, or Body, Hit Enter To Search', :class => 'form-control' %>

<% end %>
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<div id="emails">
  <%= render "emails" %>
</div>

<script>
  $(function() {
    setInterval(function(){
      $.getScript("/emails")
    }, 30000);
  });
</script>
```

**index.js.erb**

```
$("#emails").html("<%= escape_javascript render("emails") %>");
```

**emails_controller.rb**

```
  respond_to :html, :js
  def index
    @emails = current_user.emails.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
  end
```

**email.rb (search method)**

```
def self.search(search)
    if search
      where('from_email ILIKE ? OR subject ILIKE ? OR body ILIKE ?', "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%")
    else
      all
    end
  end
```

So here's what's happening.  I can type 1-2 letters and it will pull up the results, but it will not continue after that, it's like the JS just stalls.  I disabled the setInterval timer to poll for new messages and it's not working.  This is really frustrating as this works in older versions of Rails just not in the 4.2.x series.

Is this a turbolinks issue?  Or do I need to write my JS in a different fashion?  I also have jquery-turbolinks installed but it has not made a difference either way.

Any helps is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from the snippets, here, but I had a similar issue where I was positioning my form within the replaced portion of the index page. Thus, my form would accept a couple of characters, until the AJAX had time to process, and then it would replace the results (including my form) with the partial. It'd "stall." Moving my form outside the replaceable area fixed it.

That might have just been my stupid mistake; and it was easily fixed. But I thought I'd mention it.

Comment: I'm glad I found my old post, I ran into a similar issue with a Rails 5.1.3 app and solved it by killing the JS load of my search form which was being re-rendered thus losing focus